# Three.js object moving to target

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a object that moves to a target. The problem is that the x position is quicker than the z position or the z position is quicker than the x position.

What can I do that my object slows down for the x position if the z position needs more time to move?

My code in the animation function:

```
var distanceX = objectX - targetX;
var distanceZ = objectZ - targetZ;

if( distanceX < 0) {
    visitor.translateX( 0.05 );
}else {
    if( distanceX > 0) {
        visitor.translateX( -0.05 );
    }
}

if( distanceZ < 0) {
    visitor.translateZ( 0.05 );
}else{
    if( distanceZ > 0) {
        visitor.translateZ( -0.05 );
    }
}
```

Comment: `Date.now()` will always return a timestamp (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with millisecond-precision, so in this case your animation would run for just 5 milliseconds (should be `5000`). Also, you cannot just set the startTime to 1, but you need to set it to the timestamp of the animation-start time: `var startTime = Date.now();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to compute the current value as an absolute value instead of incrementally. What you are doing is basically something like this:

```
x = xLast + constantValue;
```

Instead, you could do this without needing the last value (this is called linear interpolation):

```
progress = Math.min((Date.now() - startTime) / duration, 1);
x = xStart + progress * (xEnd - xStart);
```

The progress value in this case is a value from 0 (animation start) to 1 (animation end).

If you write your animations like this, you can just set the duration for both parts to the same value. Using the three.js math utils you can even do this all at once:

```
var end = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 2);
var start = new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, -1);

// in animation-loop
var tmp = new THREE.Vector3();
var progress = Math.min((Date.now() - startTime) / duration, 1);

// tmp = progress * (end - start)
tmp.copy(end).sub(start).multiplyScalar(progress);        
object.position.copy(from).add(tmp);
```

That way you will have all components of the position move at a constant speed that arrives at the destination exactly at the same time.

You might want to have a look at animation-libaries like [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/). They can handle a lot of this quite comfortably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is to difficult for me to understand what you are explaining, but  tried something, see edited question